# Proper handling of input change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

It may be a correct behavior of change event, but the below behavior is bit annoying. When the value is updated from the field history (see explanation below), the event is not triggered.

Please see example code below. the result input field is updated with the change in input field 'input1'. The form and submit button is not fully relevant, but needed to submit a form to make the browser keep the history of field values.
To test:

1. enter any input in the field (say ABC)
2. Submit the form
3. enter first character of input from 1 (A)
4. use the down arrow to select the previous value + Enter
5. or use the mouse to select the previous value from the history
   No input change is detected.

Which event/ how should this code should modify so that an event is generated whenever the input value is changed.

thanks.

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Result:<input type="text" id="result" readonly></input>

    <form method="post" action=""> 
        <input type="text" id="input1" />   
        <button type=submit>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script >
        $(document).ready(function() {          
            $('#input1').change(
                function(){
                $('#result').val($('#input1').val());
            });      
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem, note that you have to submit a few values for the suggestions to display. http://jsfiddle.net/kaptZ/

Comment: your example works for me in the latest chrome.  you need to blur from the field to get the top field to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with jQuery.

A change event should be dispatched when the content of a control has changed and the control loses focus. In practice, the implementation of the change event is inconsistent in browsers, e.g. Firefox dispatches a change event when radio buttons are clicked on rather then when they lose focus. Also in IE, selecting a value from a list of previous values then causing a blur event doesn't fire a change event.

Note that for form controls to be successful, they **must** have a name attribute with a value. A simple test case is:

```
<form action="#"> 
    <input type="text" name="input1" onchange="alert('changed');">   
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

One solution is to use the blur event instead and compare the control's current *value* to its *defaultValue* - if they're different, perform whatever it is you were going to do for the change event. If the value may be changed a number of times, after the first time you need to compare with the last *value* onblur rather than the *defaultValue*.

Anyhow, here's a function that can be called onblur to see if a text input has changed. It needs a bit of work if you want to use it with other types of form control, but I don't think that's necessary.

```
<form action="#"> 
    <input type="text" name="input1" onblur="
      var changed = checkChanged(this);
      if (changed[0]) {
        alert('changed to: ' + changed[1]);
      }
    ">   
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

// For text inputs only
var checkChanged = (function() {

  var dataStore = [];

  return function (el) {
    var value = el.value,
        oValue;

    for (var i=0, iLen=dataStore.length; i<iLen; i+=2) {

      // If element is in dataStore, compare current value to
      // previous value
      if (dataStore[i] == el) {
        oValue = dataStore[++i];

        // If value has changed...
        if (value !== oValue) {
          dataStore[i] = value;
          return [true, value]; 

        // Otherwise, return false
        } else {
          return [false, value];
        }
      }
    }

    // Otherwise, compare value to defaultValue and
    // add it to dataStore
    dataStore.push(el, value);
    return [(el.defaultValue != value), value];
  }

}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `keyup` event:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('#input1').keyup(
            function(){
            $('#result').val($('#input1').val());
        });      
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kaptZ/7/

Comment: What? Did you try it? Doesn't work for me! Selecting an item from the suggest list does not populate #result

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's definitely a browser bug. Not much you can do besides implement your own change handler with focus and blur. This example is not very reusable, but it solved the problem and can be used as inspiration for something reusable.

http://jsfiddle.net/kaptZ/9/

```
var startValue;
var input1 = $('#input1');

input1.focus(function(){
    startValue = this.value;
});

input1.blur(function(){
    if (this.value != startValue) {
        $('#result').val(this.value);
    }
});
```

A dirty alternative is to use autocomplete="off"

Comment: it doesn't work for me ... I tried both Chrome and Iceweasel(Firefox)

Comment: What doesn't work? I tried it on Chrome and FF and it worked. Are you sure you have the correct link to right version of the jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/kaptZ/9/ You have to leave the field after selecting an entry with the mouse or by hitting enter

Comment: thanks.. I thought it may work just after the selection, not after clicking some where in the scree/other fields.. My code is part of a screen where the 'result' field is updated via ajax upon input value change.. it's bit odd that the 'result' field doesn't change even after the user made the selection. So, in the above case, the event is only triggered if the user change the focus out of the input field.. it may be confusing as they may expect the result to be updated when the correct value is in the input field..

Comment: Well, the change handler does not get called as you type by design, only when you leave the field, that's what was being emulated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20780) which was supposed to be fixed in November 2009.

In modern browsers you can use the `input` event and update as you type.  It can be bound either to the [text input](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/mqCnD/1/):

```
$('#input1').bind('input', function(){
    $('#result').val($('#input1').val());
});
```

Or to the [form](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/mqCnD/):

```
$('#input1').closest('form').bind('input', function(){
    $('#result').val($('#input1').val());
});
```