# Detecting a selection of a old value with mouse

Tags: event-handling, jquery

When i click on an `<input type=text>`, a list of old values appear. If I chose one of them with the mouse, the event "change" from jQuery doesn't trigger.

What event should/could I use to detect this?

Comment: This is a common problem. You'd be better of disabling autocomplete on the form/field. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11710295/551093

Comment: @ChristianVarga no, you can use oninput. If not supported, see keyup, paste, change events

Comment: @roasted I'm interested to know how `keyup` or `paste` would be fired when _"a value is chosen with the mouse"_. Also, the OP already stated `change` didn't work.

Comment: Same problems here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050948/proper-handling-of-input-change-event/6052322#6052322

Comment: @ChristianVarga oniput handle all these cases (paste,keyup,change...). I was just saying in case oniput is not supported, you can handle all this other events and maybe with CLICK too which should be fired when clicking on autocomplete dropdown. {this have to be verified if cross browser though}

Comment: @roasted, nah, `click` isn't always fired when selecting an option from a browser-generated autocomplete dropdown. That's the problem, browser-generated autocompletes are really painful. Some of them don't generate _any_ event.

Comment: @ChristianVarga You are right, not possible using click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `oninput` event, using jquery:

```
$('#myinput').on('input',function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`change` will only trigger if field loose it's focus (blur event). And the term *old values appear* is browser feature that remembers form data for fields with same name. You can not trigger `change` event with that. You need an alternate event like `paste` , `input`.

```
$("#field").on("input DOMAttrModified paste",function(){
});
```

I'm not sure of event. You can try some though.